# Issues with auth.log

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

My auth.log on my ubuntu server is full with

Unable to open env file: /etc/default/locale: No such file or directory

Any ideas on how to solve?

Answer (score 4):

One answer could be: Create the /etc/default/locale file...

Mine has the contents:

```
LANG="en_GB.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="en_GB:en"
```

This may be caused by [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pam/+bug/155794).  If it is, then simply running 'update-locale' may fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'LANG="en_US.UTF-8"' > /etc/default/locale
```

Possibly, replace "en_US.UTF-8" with a generated locale of your choice or just C which at least should be present.

You could check out */var/lib/locales/supported.d/local* for an indication of which locales might be generated.